# When the gap size is less than the wavelength, the angle through which the wave is diffracted remains a maximum . What does this mean?

Tags: diffraction, wavelength

When the gap size is less than the wavelength, the angle through which the wave is diffracted remains a maximum while the intensity decreases as the gap gets
smaller than the wavelength. 
I understand this statement except for this "the angle through which the wave is diffracted remains a maximum" part.
Can someone please explain what they mean here?

Comment: Could you ask some context please? What kind of gap are you talking about?  Are you talking about diffraction through one or multiple slits?

Comment: The question is about diffraction through a single slit. Its an experiment using a source and detector changing gap size to show at what lengths of gap size diffraction occurs. A graph is made. The question asked for an explanation of the graph. The mark scheme gave that explanation for why diffraction doesnt occur for gap sizes smaller than wavelengths. Im confused about the angle part. What angle are they talking about and how does it affect diffraction. Please dont use any formulas including the angle because they're out of AS level so i wont understand.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the first minimum for a slit of width $d$ when the incident wavelength is $\lambda$ is $\sin \theta = \dfrac \lambda d$ where $\theta$ is the angle of diffraction.

If $\lambda > d$ this equation has no solution and so there is no first or any other minimum.
The resulting diffraction pattern is just a central maximum.